# Instantiate custom button from code and Storyboard - how to make an init method

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I would like to create a button like this:

```
import UIKit

class EKLikeButton: UIButton {

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    self.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

  }
}
```

but the only way to make it seems to be to set a pre-existing button in a Storyboard. I'd like to be able to do:

```
let btn = EKLikeButton()
btn.frame=CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 40.0, 40.0)
```

but when I try the above, I get

> Missing argument for parameter 'coder' in call

How would I make an init function that can handle both from code or from storyboard in Swift?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what I usually do

```
class EKLikeButton: UIButton {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setUp()

    }
    init(){
        super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
        setUp()
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setUp()
    }
    func setUp(){
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        self.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That error message is telling you that it's looking for that `coder` param, because you only have that one `init` function. You haven't declared an initializer with no parameters, so you can't init like: `EKLikeButton()`

To add an init that accepts a frame parameter, you need to also implement:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    // set up your frame, init, whatever
}
```

Then you can instantiate it like this:

```
let btn = EKLikeButton(CGRect(10, 10, 40, 40))
```